# cross join with reapitive values

Tags: sql, join

I have a table "Asli" as :

```
CREATE TABLE Asli(
    clashhid INT NULL,
    TaDah INT NULL,
    DahTaPanz INT NULL,
    PanzTaBist INT NULL,
    BistTaBispan INT NULL,
    BispanTaC INT NULL,
    Marital VARCHAR(20) NULL)
```

and my inserted value is :

```
INSERT INTO Asli
 VALUES (1,2,1,0,0,0,'single')
```

when I cross join my table with this Query:

```
SELECT  clashhid,
        TaDah,
        DahTaPanz,
        PanzTaBist,
        BistTaBispan,
        BispanTaC ,
        mariStatus
  FROM asli CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('single'),('married')) AS custs (mariStatus)
```

my result set:

[image: Image1]

but I need to change values in "married" state 0 like this one:

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT  clashhid,
        CASE WHEN mariStatus = 'married' THEN 0 ELSE TaDah END AS TaDah,
        CASE WHEN mariStatus = 'married' THEN 0 ELSE DahTaPanzEND AS DahTaPanz,
        CASE WHEN mariStatus = 'married' THEN 0 ELSE PanzTaBist END AS PanzTaBist,
        CASE WHEN mariStatus = 'married' THEN 0 ELSE BistTaBispan END AS BistTaBispan,
        CASE WHEN mariStatus = 'married' THEN 0 ELSE BispanTaC END AS BispanTaC ,     
        mariStatus
FROM asli 
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('single'),('married')) AS custs (mariStatus)
```

Comment: it`s  awesome, Thanks a lot @Giorgos Betsos

Comment: @Ramin Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it help you solve your problem.

Comment: ok, and how about when i insert married state like : INSERT INTO Asli
 VALUES (1,2,1,0,0,0,'married') ? i don't want change these value either

Comment: @Ramin You can write a new post if you want to ask another question. It is generally discouraged to post and answer questions in comments here in SO.